# Clash between ocgcolorlinks option of hyperref and patterns library of TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, hyperref

I have stripped down to the following MWE after some experimentation. As it is, it works without any problems.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[ocgcolorlinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}


\author{The author}
\title{Some title}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\maketitle
\listoffigures
\mainmatter
\chapter{first}
\section{first}
Some figure
\begin{figure}%
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill,pattern=north east lines,thick] (0,0) rectangle (5cm,2cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Some caption}%
\label{fig:a1}%
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Notice the coloring and the weight of the font on LoF entries:

[image]

But when I change the location of the `hyperref` declaration to somewhere after TikZ and its library declaration, the whole figure environment just vanishes (but LoF still knows that it's there) also LoF entry loses its color(I guess!).

[image]

If I remove the patterns library dependence (`fill=yellow` or anything else) the second picture above is obtained and the TikZ picture is rendered correctly regardless of the declaring order. This suggests that the second image is the correct one and  something fishy is going on either in the pattern library or `ocgcolorlinks` option. Does anyone know why? Or is it a bug?

I work with MikTeX 2.9, [TikZ/PGF](http://texdoc.net/pkg/PGF) 2.10, [`hyperref`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/hyperref)6.83c

Comment: I couldn't replicate it here but in my original big file, the resulting PDF triggers a corrupted file error on Adobe Acrobat X on the pages where I have patterns in TikZ figures. Is it possible that ocg mechanism throws everything to another layer? I didn't test it but maybe if I print it, the story gets more mysterious.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both packages need access to the same data structures in PDF. There is nothing that manages the global resources of the PDF format. Thus the current situation is that the packages overwrite each other. At TeX macro level some kind of PDF kernel is needed, like the LaTeX kernel manages global resources like various counter registers.

**Update**: After a closer look I found that both packages overwrite the token register `\pdfpageresources` with deleting the previous contents. Of course there are problems, if the same keys are set by different packages. In this case however, `TikZ` sets `/ColorSpace`, `/Pattern` and `/ExtGState`, whereas `hyperref` puts key `/Properties` there. Therefore I will update `hyperref` to preserve the previous contents of `\pdfpageresources`. Then the example will work, if `hyperref` is loaded **after** `pgf`. The current situation is that either the `TikZ`'s patterns or `hyperref`s `ocgcolorlinks` are broken.

Comment: When I load `hyperref` version 6.83k with option `ocgcolorlinks` after loading `tikz`, I get a warning: `Package hyperref Warning: The PDF version number could not be set, because some PDF objects are already written: 3 PDF objects  The version should be set as early as possible: \pdfminorversion=5\relax.`

Comment: @AndrewUzzell Just do thus. Put `\pdfminorversion=5\relax` at the beginning before `\documentclass` (or before the first PDF object is written).